# Is Patent 13/284,678 Granted? Patent granted for Flipboard flipping?

Tags: patent-infringement, patent-applications, us20130111395

Hi can i ask if this patent is granted? I see a publication date, but not sure if it was granted.

Am thinking for a flipping metaphor similar to Flipboard

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This application was not granted and is still pending. Additionally, the Patent Office has not made any determinations yet as to whether the invention is new and not obvious. The application has been waiting for examination for a few years now (since 2011), so it should be reviewed by the Patent Office in (relatively) short order.

You can find more details at http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair by completing the CAPTCHA and entering in the application number (13/284678). The "Transaction History" and "Image File Wrapper" tabs contain the history and documents, respectively, of the application.

Comment: thanks! if I use the flipping metaphor now, and assuming that the patent were to be granted later, would it be considered as infringing it and therefore required to remove it?